# Meson conditional address sanitization

Tags: meson-build

I basically want to do something like this

```
if get_option('buildtype') == 'debug'
    add_project_arguments('-fsanitize=address', language : 'c')
    add_project_link_arguments('-fsanitize=address', language : 'c')
endif
```

except using the `b_sanitize=address` option since the above generates warnings. Is this possible? I have a suspicion it might not be seeing as you can't change options outside of `project()` but I'm hoping there's a way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't change options outside of project()"? What you've written should work.

Comment: Provided that those functions are called before any others that utilize their result, e.g. any `executable` call that uses the same language.

Comment: @bool3max I can do that however meson gives me a warning telling me that I shouldn't do that but should instead set the meson flag `b_sanitize=address` which will cause meson to set the appropriate compiler flags for me. The problem is meson options such as `b_sanitize` can only be set in the project declaration as far as I know. My question is, is there a way to do this the meson recommended way or do I have to live with the warnings caused by manually setting those compiler flags

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: (He never posted an answer :( )